# WPF : why two way communication between UI and Rendering thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I not getting why two way communication between UI and Rendering thread in WPF architecture ??.

UI thread transfers the Visual composition data to Rendering thread to render on UI. But why and what data is transferred from Rendering thread to UI.

And even I want to know the How user interaction is handled in WPF.

Can I get good link where I can read or understand the UI interaction handling in WPF.
How user interaction on UI is handled in WPF.

[image]

Comment: The question is unclear. Please be more specific.

Comment: I have added more specific and clear diagram to explain my question.

Answer (score 0):

A [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) is responsible for managing the work for a thread.

The UI thread is the thread that renders the UI.

The UI thread queues work items inside an object called a Dispatcher. The Dispatcher selects work items on a priority basis and runs each one to completion. Every UI thread must have at least one Dispatcher, and each Dispatcher can execute work items in exactly one thread.

[From this article. Read it for a more thorough description of the UI Rendering in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)